# MPMoviePlayerViewController Enable Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape

I am adding an MPMoviePlayerViewController to my app like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *vc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vc];
```

Everything is working but I can't enable landscape mode. I want my whole app except the actual MPMoviePlayerViewController to be portrait. I searched on google but all the solutions require having the rest of the app also in landscape.I need my app to stay in Portrait except in the MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Using @matt answer I added landscape to my Device Orientation:

[image]

Next I went to my First View Controller(Not the MPMoviePlayerViewController) and added:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

However the app still let's the Main Menu go to Landscape mode.

Comment: But if the First View Controller is in, say, a navigation controller or a tab bar controller, then it is not the First View Controller but the navigation controller or tab bar controller that you need to worry about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually there is a way to just make Movie Player landscape without affecting portrait view of rest of screens.

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)

MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com"]];

moviePlayerVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
moviePlayerVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));

[self presentViewController:moviePlayerVC animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

---

### *Make sure you are using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and not `MPMoviePlayerController`, else it won't work.*

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried about 10 different solutions, from subclassing the view controllers, to changing the delegate, etc. This worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks <Chandresh>  ...Saved a lots of time of mine

Comment: Make sure you are using `MPMoviePlayerViewController ` and not `MPMoviePlayerController`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that MPMoviePlayerViewController is not your class so you have no control over its response to `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, which is what you would use to dictate the orientation of the presented view if this were your own view controller class. So you must *make* it your own view controller class. You will have to create your own MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass so that you can override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and express what orientation you want (i.e. landscape). Create and present an instance of that subclass, not the built-in superclass.

Comment: Will this also keep the rest of my app portrait?

Comment: You keep the rest of your app portrait by keeping the rest of your app portrait (i.e., every other view controller also must implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, to say that it wants to be portrait).

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 6.4, Swift 1.2 edited @Chandresh Panchasara answer a bit.

```
let movieC = MPMoviePlayerViewController()
        movieC.moviePlayer.contentURL = self.movieURL
        movieC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
        movieC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        movieC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat((M_PI * (90.0) / 180.0)));
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(self)
        self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answers it helped me.

For those who want it for Swift 4 here the solution:

```
playerVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
playerVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: degreesToRadian(90.0))
present(strongPlayerVC, animated: true)
```

Here the function degreesToRadian:

```
func degreesToRadian(_ degrees: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return .pi * degrees / 180.0
}
```

Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score -2):

The best way so far is to implement this AppDelegate function and check if the `rootViewController` has a child of type `AVPlayerViewController` then you return `[.portrait, .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]` and else `.portrait`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let _ = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.first as? AVPlayerViewController {
        return [.portrait, .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]
    }
    return .portrait
}
```

You should check on the `keyWindow` of `UIApplication` because apple presents this viewController in a another `UIWindow` so if you try to do that check on the window that is declared in the `AppDelegate` this won't work so be careful.